# How can I use Selenium to navigate a pop-up calendar with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This is a hobby project so I can get more familiar with Selenium.

I have a list of dates.  I want to get the movie times for each of those dates.  I can load the theater site and calendar without any issues, but when I get to selecting the specific day I get snagged.  How can I use Selenium to click on the day inside the calendar?

Here is what I have so far.  Open browser, load page, click and open calendar:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
url = "https://www.amctheatres.com/movie-theatres/los-angeles/amc-promenade-16"
browser.get(url)
browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='showtime-date']").click()
browser.implicitly_wait(3)
```

My three attempts so far that haven't worked.

**Attempt 1:**                                                                                                 When I try to find the link by text I get:

> NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element

```
elem = browser.find_element_by_link_text('28').click()
```

**Attempt 2:**
this xpath finds the element and the click method works, but I want to be able to pick a day by string text

```
xpath = ".//*[@id='theatre-showtimes-202']/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[5]"     
elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()
```

**Attempt 3:**
finding the element by xpath and text works, but then the click method doesn't do anything

```
xpath_by_text = '//td[contains(text(), "28")]'
elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_by_text).click()
```

What can I do to find the calendar day by the day number and then click on it?

Comment: You can use absolute xpath instead of relative one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Attempt 1: When I try to find the link by text

This does not work since "by link text" locator searches through *`a` elements only*. You need a `td` element.

> Attempt 2 ...

As you've already noted, it is not what you want to do. You need to locate the element *by text*.

> Attempt 3

This is very close to the desired result, but, as you may see, *there are two elements with `28` text*. You are finding the first `td` (because, according to the [WebDriver specification](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#element-location-strategies): *"All element location strategies must return elements in the order in which they appear in the current document"*) which is disabled (which explains why the click does nothing) and is coming from the previous month.

Instead, locate the `td` element by text and, additionally, skip elements containing `disabled` in the class attribute value:

```
//td[. = "28" and not(contains(@class, "disabled"))]
```

Demo from the Chrome Console:

```
> $x('//td[. = "28"]')
[<td class=​"old disabled day">​28​</td>​, <td class=​"day">​28​</td>​]

> $x('//td[. = "28" and not(contains(@class, "disabled"))]')
[<td class=​"day">​28​</td>​]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this solution

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.amctheatres.com/movie-theatres/los-angeles/amc-promenade-16");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/input[1]")).click();   driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[5]")).click();

Comment: The question is python-specific.

Comment: The answer is perfect for java, but not for python. But python user can get help from this concept

Comment: @RiponAlWasim well, even if this is java, the answer is far from being perfect: first of all, implicit waits are often not-reliable and make your tests slower. Also, you don't need to manipulate implicit waits multiple times - it just instructs the webdriver how long to wait before trying to find an element - usually it is called once at the beginning. Plus, the XPath expressions used in the answer are very fragile and complex because they depend on the complete HTML structure of the page. I can go on :)

Comment: @alecxe I would appreciate if you can share how I can make this script more perfect

Comment: @alecxe: You are correct that, complicated and absolute xpath is not recommended to use. But in very few cases it needs to use absolute xpath as relative xpath doesn't work. I guess, this is one of the cases.

Comment: @Ripon Al Wasim agreed with you I used relative xpath in one of my live project, but I didn't work as expected so I used absolute xpath and it worked fine

Comment: Code of implicit wait works for all elements commonly. So no need to repeat it several times.